# Como atribuo uma função a ContextMenuStrip em c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Como atribuo uma função a um ContextMenuStrip que está em um NotifyIcon?

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
private void Thread_Notify_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Thread_Notify.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
}

void Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread_Notify.Visible = false;
    Application.Exit();
}
```

O menu já está habiltado e funcionando perfeitamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso atribuir a função Exit() à opção sair (sairToolStripMenuItem) do menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só adicionar o método como evento do `Click` do item.

```
sairToolStripMenuItem.Click += Exit;
```